# How to make 'access_type=offline' / server-only OAuth2 operations on GAE/Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

This post is a followup to *[How to do OAuth-requiring operations in a GAE cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863661/how-to-do-oauth-requiring-operations-in-a-gae-cron-job/16864183?noredirect=1#comment24330008_16864183)*, where I realized I'm mis-using the `@oauth_required` decorator from `OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets`.

As described by the [OAuth 2.0 explained](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#oauth) presentation, Oauth 2.0 solves the problem of:

- Building a **service**...
- ... accessed by a **user**...
- ... ***and accessing the user's data from a third party***.

That's what `@oauth_required` abstracts, and it does it well (currently my app "works": if I trigger the refresh page, I'm being asked to authorize access to my youtube data to my app, and the rest follows). But that's not what I want! My app does something simpler, which is creating a youtube playlist every day with *my* credentials and *without any user input*. So to compare to the above 3-tier negociation, I want:

- A **service**
- ... accessed by **users**
- ... ***but only accessing "server-owned" YouTube playlist data.*** I don't want any access to the user's YouTube data, I just want to modify a playlist I (i.e. me / a userid persisted by the server) own.

But I still need help to do that; here is my current state:

1. After a few searches I learned that what I want to do is called [Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) (emphasis mine, which is almost exactly my use case):
   *"In some cases, your application may need to access a Google API when the user is not present. Examples of this include backup services and applications that **make blogger posts exactly at 8am on Monday morning**. This style of access is called offline, and web server applications may request offline access from a user. The normal and default style of access is called online."*...
   → So I should keep doing what I'm doing right now, keep requesting access to my YouTube account, but do it using the `type_access=offline` flag to get a token, and persist/use it for subsequent requests.
2. The *[Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline)* and  *Using a Refresh Token* sections make total sense, but stay at a general HTTP level. Being still a newbie, I don't see how to integrate those principles into my Python code, and I didn't find any sample Python code around....
   → Could anyone help me with one Python example illustrating how and where to use this flag?
3. ... and in particular, after studying `oauth2client.appengine.OAuth2Decorator.oauth_required`, I'm still not sure if I can bend it to my case, or if I should do my own thing.
   → What do you think?

Thanks for your time; if needed I'm also hanging out on irc://irc.freenode.net/#appengine as `ronj`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Offline access is the [default](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/oauth2client/client.py?r=ae2ff74e239820776304fadcba8f9b476efd913b#1201) when retrieving tokens; you may have noticed this in the OAuth dialog that comes up:

> Perform these operations when I'm not using the application

When your user accepts the OAuth dialog in a method decorated with `decorator.oauth_required` the credentials for that user will be stored in the datastore, **including** the refresh token.

Once you have one of these credentials objects, you can use it so authorize an HTTP object for calling APIS:

```
import httplib2
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

and once authorized, it will do all the work for you. So if the `access_token` is expired, the first API response will be a `401` and so the `credentials` object will use the `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token` and make the request again.

If you know the user ID, you can retrieve the `credentials` from the datastore as described in [How to do OAuth-requiring operations in a GAE Task Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842433/how-to-do-oauth-requiring-operations-in-a-gae-task-queue/):

```
from oauth2client.appengine import CredentialsModel
from oauth2client.appengine import StorageByKeyName
credentials = StorageByKeyName(
     CredentialsModel, user_id, 'credentials').get()
```

## Note/Gotcha:

If a user has already authorized your client ID, the subsequent times you perform OAuth for these users they will not see the OAuth dialog and you won't be given a refresh token. A refresh token can **only** be given if they go through the OAuth dialog, but since the user had already authorized your client ID, the spec assumes you would already have a refresh token around.

This often comes up when developers are testing OAuth, since they will go through the flow multiple times with a test account and after accepting the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... times, they never see the refresh token. A simple way around this is to use `approval_prompt=force` as an argument to the `OAuth2Decorator` constructor. This will force the OAuth dialog to appear every time you perform OAuth for a user.

However, this **will not** cause the dialog to show up every time a request is served for a given user; this would be a **TERRIBLE** user experience. Instead, the `SACSID` cookie from the request can be used (by the client library and some App Engine libraries) to determine who the current user is. Once the the library knows that current user, it can get your existing **stored** token/`credentials` for that user from the datastore and no jarring dialog will be needed.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm doing everything as expected including getting credentials. But then we're back to my root problem, which is that when deployed and launched manually it works, but when launched through GAE's Cron, it just shows "Failed" in red, my script is not called, and all I can see in the instance log is: `2013-06-07 /fetch 302 4ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)  0.1.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2013:08:20:00 -0700] "GET /fetch HTTP/1.1" 302 385 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "myapp.appspot.com" ms=4 cpu_ms=0 ...` What could be wrong?

Comment: Got what's wrong from Greg Darke's answer on [this GAE mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/uuX8Z_ZX1cA): *"Redirects are not followed by the cron system."* So I separated my manual first fetch page from the cron one, and de-annotated the cron one, but now I'm unable to `http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())`, even though I set `credentials = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user_id, 'credentials').get()`. What can I do?

Comment: This should work, we'd need to see more code to really tell you what you're doing wrong. It is **EXPECTED** behavior that auth only URIs fail for cron jobs and that cron jobs don't follow the auth redirects.

Comment: Hi @bossylobster I did some cleanup before publishing my code, which let me do progress, but I am now stuck with a a `invalid_grant` error, documented on [How to avoid 'Failed to retrieve access token: { “error” : “invalid_grant” }' in offline GAE cron tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024282/how-to-avoid-failed-to-retrieve-access-token-error-invalid-grant-in). Can you have a look? Thanks for your help.