# Get Google Account email address based on user_id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail-api

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16847739/1020763) by @bossylobster, I have successfully implemented a cron job that connects with the GMail API. Currently I have the user_id and email address in my code, however I am building an app where it should run through a list of users.

Problem in that case is that when I run a loop on the CredentialsModel, I don't have the user's email address. Since I am using the User model from webapp 2 (based on [this tutorial](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/)), I also can't look this ID up anywhere (as far as I know).

If I could somehow retrieve the email address with the user_id and credentials, or save the email address and user_id in the user model at the moment the permissions are given... What would be the best way to handle this?

My code for getting authorization:

```
http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
service = discovery.build("gmail", "v1", http=http)
decorator = OAuth2Decorator(client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,
                        client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
                        scope=settings.SCOPE)

class getPermissions(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @decorator.oauth_aware
  def get(self):
    template_values = {
    'url': decorator.authorize_url(),
    'has_credentials': decorator.has_credentials()
    }
    self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/auth.html', template_values))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Run a loop on the CredentialsModel"?

Comment: Calling all entities in the CredentialsModel and using them to execute my API call. Does that explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gmail API-specific method**

You can call [users.getProfile()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile) to get an email address for the user:

```
user_profile = service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()
user_email = user_profile['emailAddress']
```

this method has the advantage of not requiring you to add any additional API scopes.

**Generic Method**

If you add `email` to your list of OAuth scopes, then your credentials object will include the user's email address:

```
try:
  print credentials.id_token['email']
except KeyError:
  print 'Unknown email'
```

See [Google's docs for the email scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email-scopes).

Answer (score 2):

You can call the Gmail API with userId="me" which means, just use the userId of the authenticated user from the credential--don't need to specify an email address/userId.  c.f. the description for the userId field in the docs:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list

Comment: Thanks, that will solve most of the problem. Nevertheless I'd like to know what user on my app matches with what credentials. Is it e.g. reliable / recommendable to save the user_id and do a google people API call directly on signup?